# PyQt5 reading values from multiple Qwidgets and transform to class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, return-value

In order to do some calculation, I need to read some information values, which it sets by user on different widgets and values should later pass to a class, by clicking on a button. The class activates and calculates some data, then later that data pass to some other widget in order to plot or write....

We need also to flag when one or more data lacking before proceeding to class.

**Visualisation:**

Figur 1: button clicks by user then it proceeds and reads values from multiple Widget tabs and pass those data to a class.

[image]

Figur 2: Information usually set by user for further reading.

[image]

Figur 3: Information usually set by user for reading.

[image]

Figur 4: Information usually set by user for reading.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Figur 5: Information usually set by user for reading.

[image]

**The entire code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Tabwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Tabwidget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 230)      
        tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.geometry = firsttab()
        self.roundsection = self.geometry

        self.A = ClassA()
        self.B = ClassB()
        self.C = ClassC()

        tab.addTab(self.geometry,'A')
        tab.addTab(self.A,'B')
        tab.addTab(self.B,'C')
        tab.addTab(self.C, 'D')
        tab.addTab(LoadTable(), 'E')
        tab.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(tab)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)


class firsttab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    valuesChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(firsttab, self).__init__(parent)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Georgia",8,QtGui.QFont.Normal)

        sectiontypegroupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('&Type',self)
        sectiontypegroupbox.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",10,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        tab1button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('')


        circularlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Calculate",self)
        circularlabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        circularlabel.setFont(font)


        circularlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        circularlay.addWidget(tab1button)
        circularlay.addWidget(circularlabel)


        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addLayout(circularlay)
        vboxlayout.setSizeConstraint(vboxlayout.SetFixedSize)
        vboxlayout.setContentsMargins(25,25,25,25)

        sectiontypegroupbox.setLayout(vboxlayout)   

        hboxlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hboxlayout.addWidget(sectiontypegroupbox)
        self.setLayout(hboxlayout)

#        self.button = Calculate()        
#        tab1button.clicked.connect(self.button.parse_file)



class ClassA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))      

        self.c_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fctd = "One\n\nTwo\n\nThree"
        con_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel(fctd)
        self.value = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Test')
        self.c_lay.addWidget(con_strength)
        self.c_lay.addWidget(self.value, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)


        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["10","12","14","16"])

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.con = QtWidgets.QLabel("Number: ")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.con)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.c_lay)
        self.vlay.addStretch()

        Concrete_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Concrete_Group.setTitle("&GroupA")
        Concrete_Group.setLayout(self.vlay)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(Concrete_Group)

        self.comth = ["10","12","14","16"]
        self.combo.activated.connect(self.setdatastrength)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setdatastrength(self, index):
        value = self.comth[index]
        self.display_data(value)


    def display_data(self, value):
        try:

            f = value
            f_value = "{}"
            self.value.setText(f_value.format(f))

        except ValueError:
            print("Error")


class ClassB(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))


        self.combo_exclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_exclass.addItems([" Very dry area"," Dry or permanently wet"," Wet, rarely dry"," Moderate humidity"," Tidal splash & spray zones"])


        self.combo_lclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_lclass.addItems(["L2","L4","L6","L8"])

        self.combo_vct = QtWidgets.QComboBox()


        self.combo_vct.addItems(["0.10","0.20","0.30","0.40",
                                        "0.50","0.60","0.70"])

        self.combo_in = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_in.addItems(["Class1","Class2","Class3"])        

        self.tbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.exclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class1: ")
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.exclass)
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.combo_exclass)


        self.mtbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class2: ")

        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.lclass)
        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.combo_lclass)


        self.mbbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vct = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class3: ")
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.vct)
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.combo_vct)

        self.bbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.inl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class4: ")
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.inl)
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.combo_in)


        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(self.tbox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mtbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mbbox, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.bbox, 3, 0)

        Environment_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Environment_Group.setTitle("&Group2")
        Environment_Group.setLayout(self.grid)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(Environment_Group)


class ClassC(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassC, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))      


        filenameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name number:")
        fileNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()


        ftablayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        ftablayout.addWidget(filenameLabel)
        ftablayout.addWidget(fileNameEdit)
        self.setLayout(ftablayout)

class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 3, parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("A","B","C")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)

        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 2, combox_lay)

class Calculate():
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g):

        self.x_value = None
        self.a_frc = None
        self.b_cap = None
        self.bsst = None
        self.tsst = None
        self.bsst = None
        self.tsstr = None
        self.parse_file(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

    def parse_file(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
        #all the code for calculation where:
        pass
        self.x_value = '{:.3f}'.format(a)
        self.a_frc = '{:.3f}'.format(b)
        self.b_cap = '{:.3f}'.format(c)
        self.bsst = '{:.3f}'.format(d)
        self.tsst = '{:.3f}'.format(e)
        self.bsst = '{:.3f}'.format(f)
        self.tsstr = '{:.3f}'.format(g)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('\nx value: {0} \nAforce: {1} \nb capacity : {2} \nBottom strain : {3} '
                '\nTop strain : {4} \nBottom stress :{5} \nTop stress : {6}'
                .format(self.x_value, self.a_frc, self.b_cap, self.bsst, self.tsst, self.bsst, self.tsstr))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tabwidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not point out what you want to get, I'll point out the general method: you have to have a method that obtains the data:

```
class Some_Widget(FooWidget):
    # ...
    def get_data(self):
         return some_values
```

In the case of FirstTab I do not understand the signals that you have created, IMHO I think you only need a signal called clicked that is issued when the clicked signal of the button is transmitted and transmits it to the main window where the data can be accessed.

On the other hand, delete the `{:.3f}` part because the data is not numeric but strings (maybe you have to convert them to strings but since there are no details, that's it) so I'll just print it

Considering the above and assuming several things since you do not point out anything concrete the following code is a possible solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Tabwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Tabwidget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 230)      
        tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.geometry = FirstTab()
        self.geometry.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.A = ClassA()
        self.B = ClassB()
        self.C = ClassC()

        self.load_table = LoadTable()

        tab.addTab(self.geometry,'A')
        tab.addTab(self.A,'B')
        tab.addTab(self.B,'C')
        tab.addTab(self.C, 'D')
        tab.addTab(self.load_table, 'E')
        tab.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",9,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addWidget(tab)
        self.setLayout(vboxlayout)

        self._calculate = Calculate()

    def on_clicked(self):
        d1 = self.A.get_data()
        d2 = self.B.get_data()
        d3 = self.C.get_data()
        d4 = self.load_table.get_data()
        self._calculate.parse_file(*d1, *d2, *d3, *d4)


class FirstTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FirstTab, self).__init__(parent)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Georgia",8,QtGui.QFont.Normal)

        sectiontypegroupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('&Type',self)
        sectiontypegroupbox.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Georgia",10,QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        tab1button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()


        circularlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Calculate",self)
        circularlabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        circularlabel.setFont(font)


        circularlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        circularlay.addWidget(tab1button)
        circularlay.addWidget(circularlabel)


        vboxlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vboxlayout.addLayout(circularlay)
        vboxlayout.setSizeConstraint(vboxlayout.SetFixedSize)
        vboxlayout.setContentsMargins(25,25,25,25)

        sectiontypegroupbox.setLayout(vboxlayout)   

        hboxlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hboxlayout.addWidget(sectiontypegroupbox)
        tab1button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)


class ClassA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))      

        self.c_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        fctd = "One\n\nTwo\n\nThree"
        con_strength = QtWidgets.QLabel(fctd)
        self.value = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Test')
        self.c_lay.addWidget(con_strength)
        self.c_lay.addWidget(self.value, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["10","12","14","16"])

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.con = QtWidgets.QLabel("Number: ")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.con)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.combo)

        self.vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vlay.addLayout(self.c_lay)
        self.vlay.addStretch()

        Concrete_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Concrete_Group.setTitle("&GroupA")
        Concrete_Group.setLayout(self.vlay)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(Concrete_Group)

        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.display_data)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def display_data(self, value):
        try:
            f = value
            f_value = "{}"
            self.value.setText(f_value.format(f))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error")

    def get_data(self):
        return tuple([self.combo.currentText(), self.value.text()])

class ClassB(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))


        self.combo_exclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_exclass.addItems([" Very dry area"," Dry or permanently wet"," Wet, rarely dry"," Moderate humidity"," Tidal splash & spray zones"])


        self.combo_lclass = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_lclass.addItems(["L2","L4","L6","L8"])

        self.combo_vct = QtWidgets.QComboBox()


        self.combo_vct.addItems(["0.10","0.20","0.30","0.40",
                                        "0.50","0.60","0.70"])

        self.combo_in = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo_in.addItems(["Class1","Class2","Class3"])        

        self.tbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.exclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class1: ")
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.exclass)
        self.tbox.addWidget(self.combo_exclass)


        self.mtbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lclass = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class2: ")

        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.lclass)
        self.mtbox.addWidget(self.combo_lclass)

        self.mbbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vct = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class3: ")
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.vct)
        self.mbbox.addWidget(self.combo_vct)

        self.bbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.inl = QtWidgets.QLabel("Class4: ")
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.inl)
        self.bbox.addWidget(self.combo_in)


        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(self.tbox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mtbox, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.mbbox, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.bbox, 3, 0)

        Environment_Group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        Environment_Group.setTitle("&Group2")
        Environment_Group.setLayout(self.grid)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(Environment_Group)

    def get_data(self):
        return tuple(combo.currentText() for combo in (self.combo_exclass, self.combo_lclass, self.combo_vct, self.combo_in))


class ClassC(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClassC, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))      

        filenameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name number:")
        self.fileNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        ftablayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        ftablayout.addWidget(filenameLabel)
        ftablayout.addWidget(self.fileNameEdit)

    def get_data(self):
        return tuple(self.fileNameEdit.text(),)


class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoadTable, self).__init__(1, 3, parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Helvetica", 10, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))   
        headertitle = ("A","B","C")
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headertitle)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 130)

        combox_lay = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        combox_lay.addItems(["I","II"])
        self.setCellWidget(0, 2, combox_lay)

    def get_data(self):
        return tuple([self.cellWidget(0, 2).currentText()])

class Calculate():
    def parse_file(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
        print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tabwidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
# ...
class LoadTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    # ...
    def get_data(self):
        val1 = self.item(0, 0).text()  if self.item(0, 0) else ""
        val2 = self.item(0, 1).text()  if self.item(0, 1) else ""
        return tuple([val1, val2, self.cellWidget(0, 2).currentText()])

# ...
class Calculate():
    def parse_file(self,a,b,c,d,e,f,g, h, i):
        print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I want. maybe one last piece lacking is to return value from table.

Comment: @ZarKha but you want 7 values (a, b, c, ..g) but with the data of the table would be 9